# tkinter: How to make the label disappear after outputting all of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to output a list, one by one, in a specific amount of time. The code below outputs the list but I don't know how to make it disappear after that.

```
import tkinter as tk

i=0
list=["a","b","c"]

def wordeasy3_label(label):
    def wordeasy3():
        global i
        label.config(text=(list[i]))
        label.place(x=0,y=0)
        i+=1
        label.after(2000, wordeasy3)
    wordeasy3()

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
wordeasy3_label(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think for the community to be helpful, you'll need to be a bit more clear about what you are seeing vs. what you expect to see. [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) gives a few tips on making your question clear and answerable. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an if statement:

```
 def wordeasy3_label(label):
    def wordeasy3():
        global i
        if i != 3: 
            label.config(text=(list[i]))
            label.place(x=0,y=0)
            i+=1
            label.after(2000, wordeasy3)
        else:
            label.destroy()
    wordeasy3()
```